# Need Shell Script To Check If a kernel is over 4.1

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I need a script that checks if a kernel is over 4.1 and if it is it runs the script if its not it doesn't, Please help.
- Prajwal

Something like this but with kernel check

```
  if ! [ -x "$(command -v iptables)" ]; then
    echo "Error: iptables is not installed, please install iptables." >&2
    exit
  fi
```

```
#!/bin/bash
version_above_4(){
    # check if $BASH_VERSION is set at all
    [ -z $BASH_VERSION ] && return 1

    # If it's set, check the version
    case $BASH_VERSION in 
        4.*) return 0 ;;
        ?) return 1;; 
    esac
}

if version_above_4
then
    echo "Good"
else
    echo "No good"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
VERSION_LIMIT=4.1
CURRENT_VERSION=$(uname -r | cut -c1-3)
if (( $(echo "$CURRENT_VERSION > $VERSION_LIMIT" |bc -l) )); then
    echo " Kernel version: $CURRENT_VERSION > Version Limit: $VERSION_LIMIT "
    return 0
else
    echo " Kernel version: $CURRENT_VERSION < Version Limit: $VERSION_LIMIT "
    return 1
fi
```

Comment: A+ This is the best one and has been used on the script here.
https://github.com/complexorganizations/wireguard-manager

Comment: Nice! @PrajwalKoirala

Comment: What about cases like comparing 4.15 and 4.1? I think this is better: `cut -d"." -f1,2`. Get the first two fields, rather than just the first 3 characters.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want. I use `uname -r` to print the kernel version, then `awk` to split on the periods and check the major and minor version numbers.
`version_over_4_1` will return 1 or 0.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

version_over_4_1(){
    return $(uname -r | awk -F '.' '{
        if ($1 < 4) { print 1; }
        else if ($1 == 4) {
            if ($2 <= 1) { print 1; }
            else { print 0; }
        }
        else { print 0; }
    }')
}

if version_over_4_1
then
    echo "Kernel > 4.1"
else
    echo "Kernel <= 4.1"
fi
```

Comment: See i love this but for a average user to read this its way too complicated.

can you please reduce this to a simple function something like the first one. so anyone reading this can understand, this is for a open source app that people read and use.

Comment: A bunch of conditionals is too complicated? Not sure I agree with that, this is no more complicated than if I used, say, Python to split a version number on `.` and used the same logic there.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

version_over_4_1(){
  MAJOR_VERSION=$(uname -r | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')
  MINOR_VERSION=$(uname -r | awk -F '.' '{print $2}')
  if [ $MAJOR_VERSION -ge 4 ] && [ $MINOR_VERSION -gt 1 ] || [ $MAJOR_VERSION -ge 5 ] ; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
```

This has the disadvantage of calling `awk` and `uname` twice, but may be more intuitive than methods that do not.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

version_over_4_1(){
  read MAJOR_VERSION MINOR_VERSION <<<$(uname -r | awk -F '.' '{print $1, $2}')
  if [ $MAJOR_VERSION -ge 4 ] && [ $MINOR_VERSION -gt 1 ] || [ $MAJOR_VERSION -ge 5 ] ; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
```

This calls `awk` and `uname` only once each, but might not be as intuitive as you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Lets check the kernel version
function kernel-check() {
  CURRENT_KERNEL_VERSION=$(uname --kernel-release | cut --delimiter="." --fields=1-2)
  CURRENT_KERNEL_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo "${CURRENT_KERNEL_VERSION}" | cut --delimiter="." --fields=1)
  CURRENT_KERNEL_MINOR_VERSION=$(echo "${CURRENT_KERNEL_VERSION}" | cut --delimiter="." --fields=2)
  ALLOWED_KERNEL_VERSION="3.1"
  ALLOWED_KERNEL_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo ${ALLOWED_KERNEL_VERSION} | cut --delimiter="." --fields=1)
  ALLOWED_KERNEL_MINOR_VERSION=$(echo ${ALLOWED_KERNEL_VERSION} | cut --delimiter="." --fields=2)
  if [ "${CURRENT_KERNEL_MAJOR_VERSION}" -lt "${ALLOWED_KERNEL_MAJOR_VERSION}" ]; then
    echo "Error: Kernel ${CURRENT_KERNEL_VERSION} not supported, please update to ${ALLOWED_KERNEL_VERSION}."
    exit
  fi
  if [ "${CURRENT_KERNEL_MAJOR_VERSION}" == "${ALLOWED_KERNEL_MAJOR_VERSION}" ]; then
    if [ "${CURRENT_KERNEL_MINOR_VERSION}" -lt "${ALLOWED_KERNEL_MINOR_VERSION}" ]; then
      echo "Error: Kernel ${CURRENT_KERNEL_VERSION} not supported, please update to ${ALLOWED_KERNEL_VERSION}."
      exit
    fi
  fi
}

kernel-check
```

For anyone still looking for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).